# Lenovo Ideapad U330p with Ubuntu 14.10 cannot connect to Galaxy s4

Tags: lenovo, ideapad, galaxy-nexus

I have tested this Galaxy S4 phone with a Gigabyte+Intel desktop with 14.10 and a Thinkpad x220 with 14.04 and both work fine. However, with this Lenovo Ideapad U330p it seems to be struggling to find the Galaxy with USB.

I tried the recommendations in [this Ubuntu Forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702) (excluding the fuse steps) and it didn't help.

Any ideas team?

Answer (score 1):

It was two problems.

1. Firstly that the USB cable did not work. The cable worked on two other computers but did not work with this computer. The cable/USB port (not sure which) had physically different sizes it seems, and when I used another cable the USB was able to create a circuit on all three computers.
2. The phone is protected by a password lock. You need to be logged into the phone to allow mtp file access to the files contained on the phone.

MTP seems to work fine in 14.10, there's just a few basic checks that need to be done for success. Well done guys!